# Pandas: drop column level & merge titles

Tags: python, pandas

As the result of a `groupby` + `unstack`, my columns now have one extra level. The function `list(df.columns.values)` shows

```
[('CompanyId', ''),
 ('CompanyName', ''),
 ('City', ''),
 ('Revenue', 2015),
 ('Revenue', 2016),
 ('Revenue', 2017)]
```

I would like to drop a level and merge these titles, to get the following result.

```
['CompanyId',
 'CompanyName',
 'City',
 'Revenue2015',
 'Revenue2016',
 'Revenue2017']
```

The function `df.droplevel(level=1)` helps me drop one level, but I'm not sure how to append the level 1 column titles to the ones at level 0 before dropping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension,` but is necessary convert `int` to `str`:

```
cols = [('CompanyId', ''),
 ('CompanyName', ''),
 ('City', ''),
 ('Revenue', 2015),
 ('Revenue', 2016),
 ('Revenue', 2017)]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols), data = [[1,1,1,1,1,1]])
print (df)
  CompanyId CompanyName City Revenue          
                                2015 2016 2017
0         1           1    1       1    1    1


df.columns = [''.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
   CompanyId  CompanyName  City  Revenue2015  Revenue2016  Revenue2017
0          1            1     1            1            1            1
```

---

```
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(x[0], str(x[1])) for x in df.columns]
print (df)
   CompanyId_  CompanyName_  City_  Revenue_2015  Revenue_2016  Revenue_2017
0           1             1      1             1             1             1
```